# Is there a way to get current imaplibrary instance from robot framework and pass to a separate python function?

Tags: python, automation, robotframework, gmail-imap, imaplib

i am stuck in a testcase where i need to check that after performing an action, email is getting triggered, if yes then email has an attachment.

for the first action i am using *Wait For Email* keyword of robotframework's  *imaplibrary* library. now for the attachment part since there is no keyword for this purpose i have written a separate python function to which i am passing *email_index* as parameter written by *Wait For Email* keyword. after that it should walk through the email and fetch attachment.

```
**robot file:**

${new_email}=    Wait For Email    sender=${sender_email}   text=${expected_content}   recipient=${recepient}   timeout=70
${file}   get_attachments   ${new_email}


**python function**

import imaplib
import email

# m is the email index passed from wait for email keyword
def get_attachments(m):
    if m.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart': #multipart messages only #getting below mentioned error in this line
        for part in m.walk():

        #find the attachment part
            print part.get_content_maintype()
            if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart': continue
            if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None: continue

        #save the attachment in the program directory
            filename = part.get_filename()
            return filename
```

**now the problem is i am unable to share or pass the imaplibrary session created by robot framework to a custom python function**. so am getting below error.

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_content_maintype'

i know there is a keyword get_library_instance() in Builtin library and am already using below code for getting selenium2libray driver instance.

```
def get_webdriver_instance():
        se2lib = BuiltIn().get_library_instance('Selenium2Library')
        return se2lib._current_browser()
```

is there any similar way to solve this issue for imaplibrary ? if not please suggest a way put for it.

Comment: As I don't have access to a working IMAP server I'm posting this as a comment. First of all, why do you think this isn't possible with the [ImapLibrary](https://rickypc.github.io/robotframework-imaplibrary/doc/ImapLibrary.html#Get%20Multipart%20Content%20Type) as it clearly supports the multi-type content keywords you seek. Second, have you tr ied the `BuiltIn().get_library_instance('ImapLibrary')` and pass it to your function? It is a generic way of getting a library instance object to work with.

Comment: Your comment doesn't provide an answer to either question I asked. What you think you need may not be what you actually need. So, please re-read my first comment and respond to those questions.

Comment: as far as i know we can only check a type of email multipart/text type using imaplibray. there is no existing keyword to check and manipulate the attachments sent in an email. like my requirement is to read attachments & download attachments. and i also tried BuiltIn().get_library_instance('ImapLibrary') but somehow it didn't seemed helpful for my case

Comment: however i achieved this by passing email_index to python function get_attachments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was not able to use the instance of imaplibrary for this purpose but found another way for achieving this. the main purpose for this question is to see how to handle gmail attachments related cases in robot framework(like check/read/downloading the attachments). below is code for it. for this below is a small custom function for achieving the same.

```
**robot file:**
Check Mail
    ${new_email}=    Wait For Email    sender=${sender_email}   text=${expected_content}   recipient=${recepient}   timeout=70
    ${file}          get_attachments   ${new_email}
    log many         ${file}   


**python function**

#index is the email index passed from wait for email keyword
def get_attachments(index):
    files=[]
    mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
    mail.login('email', 'password')
    mail.select('inbox')

    result, data = mail.uid('fetch',index, '(RFC822)')
    m = email.message_from_string(data[0][1])
    if m.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart': 
        for part in m.walk():
            #logger.console(part)

        #find the attachment part
            if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart': continue
            if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None: continue

        #save the attachment in the program directory
            filename = part.get_filename()
            files.append(filename)
            fp = open(filename, 'wb')
            fp.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
            fp.close()
        return files
```